# node.js + jpm not working after installing: JPM [error] Error: spawn EACCES

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, mozilla

I am moving from `cfx` to `jpm` After installing node.js by `sudo apt-get install nodejs` I installed jpm: `npm install jpm -g`. Now I am trying to run my addon: `jpm run -v`:

```
JPM [info] verbose set
JPM [info] Starting jpm run on Yandex translate - from anything to Russian (or from Russian to English)
JPM [info] Checking compatability bootstrap.js and install.rdf for xpi
Validating the manifest
JPM [warning] The `version` entry must be specified, and it should follow semantic
versioning rules. For example, it must be a string containing three
values indicating major, minor, and patch versions. For example:

"1.4.56"
"0.0.1"
"1.0.0rc4"

http://semver.org

JPM [info] Creating fallbacks if they are necessary..
Creating XPI
JPM [info] Creating XPI...
JPM [warning] .jpmignore does not exist, fallback to use default filter rules
JPM [info] Adding: /home/vitaly/Desktop/my-projects/extension-yandex-translate/data
JPM [info] Adding: /home/vitaly/Desktop/my-projects/extension-yandex-translate/LICENSE
JPM [info] Adding: /home/vitaly/Desktop/my-projects/extension-yandex-translate/README.md
JPM [info] Adding: /home/vitaly/Desktop/my-projects/extension-yandex-translate/bootstrap.js
JPM [info] Adding: /home/vitaly/Desktop/my-projects/extension-yandex-translate/extension-yandex-translate.iml
JPM [info] Adding: /home/vitaly/Desktop/my-projects/extension-yandex-translate/index.js
JPM [info] Adding: /home/vitaly/Desktop/my-projects/extension-yandex-translate/install.rdf
JPM [info] Adding: /home/vitaly/Desktop/my-projects/extension-yandex-translate/package.json
JPM [info] Adding: /home/vitaly/Desktop/my-projects/extension-yandex-translate/screenshot-ch-ru-long.png
JPM [info] Adding: /home/vitaly/Desktop/my-projects/extension-yandex-translate/screenshot-ch-ru.png
JPM [info] Adding: /home/vitaly/Desktop/my-projects/extension-yandex-translate/screenshot-en-ru-popup.png
JPM [info] Adding: /home/vitaly/Desktop/my-projects/extension-yandex-translate/screenshot-en-ru.png
JPM [info] Adding: /home/vitaly/Desktop/my-projects/extension-yandex-translate/screenshot-ru-en.png
JPM [info] Adding: /home/vitaly/Desktop/my-projects/extension-yandex-translate/yandex-translate-in-context.xpi
JPM [info] Adding: /home/vitaly/Desktop/my-projects/extension-yandex-translate/screenshot-hover.png
JPM [info] Adding: /home/vitaly/Desktop/my-projects/extension-yandex-translate/data/ico.png
JPM [info] Adding: /home/vitaly/Desktop/my-projects/extension-yandex-translate/data/script.js
JPM [info] XPI created at /tmp/jid1-ac4GNZhbcz2Q0A@jetpack-1.4.xpi (504ms)
JPM [info] Removing fallbacks if they were necessary..
Created XPI at /tmp/jid1-ac4GNZhbcz2Q0A@jetpack-1.4.xpi
JPM [info] Creating a new profile
JPM [info] Using temporary profile at
JPM [info]     /tmp/88631898-23e2-4ff0-9a8c-3d8da026ca6d
JPM [info] Executing Firefox binary: /usr/lib/firefox
JPM [info] Executing Firefox with args: -foreground,-no-remote,-profile,/tmp/88631898-23e2-4ff0-9a8c-3d8da026ca6d
JPM [error] Error: spawn EACCES
JPM [error] Error: spawn EACCES
```

I think I need to make `chmod +x` to some file of node.js, but what is it file?

Also, my `package.json` have line `"version: 1.4"` and with `xfc` all was correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [bug in JPM](https://github.com/mozilla/jpm/issues/287).

You can run your add-on with `jpm` with the following command:

```
jpm run -b $(which firefox)
```

`$(which firefox)` gets the path to your firefox binary.